# truffle account lock

Tags: truffle

I was trying to deploy the default truffle project following this guide: https://steemit.com/ethereum/@brennanhm/ethereum-smart-contract-testing-installing-truffle-and-testrpc

I am running the sample test project (truffle test) However, an error that keeps appearing is this:

[image]

Any help please?

Answer (score 3):

This means, the account that you are using to deploy the contract (most of the time coinbase) is locked.

start geth with `--unlock <ACC_INDEX>` to unlock the wallet. `0` to unlock coinbase and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Was able to run it now. I realised it was because I did geth rpc 8485.. in the second console. Instead just do testrpc in the second console.